# how to select top n values from a data frame retaining the duplicates in r

Tags: r, rank

let's say my sample data looks as below.

```
   id freq
    1    4
    2    3
    3    2
    4    2
    5    1
```

*freq* column tells the frequency of each id. The question is: I want the top 3 frequencies. the output should be..

```
   id freq
    1    4
    2    3
    3    2
    4    2
```

I used the following code.

```
d$rank <- rank(-d$freq,ties.method="min")
```

where `d` is my data frame. I used `rank` command so that i can later select top 3 frequencies.
The output i got is:

```
id freq rank
 1    4    1
 2    3    2
 3    2    3
 4    2    3
 5    1    5
```

The problem is rank 4 is missing. I want continuous ranks to handle many duplicated values in my original data frame. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 'freq' is ordered in descending, we get the `unique` elements of 'freq', select the first 3 with `head`, use `%in%` to get the logical index of those elements that in the 'freq' column, and `subset` the rows.

```
subset(df1, freq %in% head(unique(freq),3))
#  id freq
#1  1    4
#2  2    3
#3  3    2
#4  4    2
```

---

If we are using `rank`, then `dense_rank` from `dplyr` will be an option

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(dense_rank(-freq) < 4)
```

---

Or another option using `frank` from  `data.table` (contributed by @David Arenburg),

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[frank(-freq, ties.method = "dense") < 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another base R approach:

```
df[cumsum(!duplicated(df$freq))<4,]
#  id freq
#1  1    4
#2  2    3
#3  3    2
#4  4    2
```

This assumes the data is already in descending order (as in the example).

In case you're going to use external libraries like dplyr, I'd suggest using `top_n`:

```
library(dplyr)
top_n(df, 3, freq)
#  id freq
#1  1    4
#2  2    3
#3  3    2
#4  4    2
```